# Ghidra IAT address

Tags: file, memory, disk, portable-executable

Could anyone please tell me when ASLR is enabled for a program? When I load for example chrome.exe into x64 dbg I see a different ImageBase then the one in the optional header. However, I also load two ransomware samples (32 bit) and both of them had the same ImageBase as in the static PE File (In that case the ImageBase of the static PE file + the RVA of an API function is IAT = the virtual addresss in memory). Can anybody provide me more information?